# Batch IF statement always returning false?

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, windows-7, cmd

OK, so I have this:

```
:ask
SET /p answer = Hello user. Do you want to use this program? (y/n) 

IF [/i] %answer% == y GOTO yes
IF [/i] %answer% == n (GOTO no) ELSE (ECHO Your input was not accepted. Please try again. & GOTO ask)

:yes
...
...

:no
pause
```

The problem is that both if statements are returning false and it is constantly asking for my input. I wanted it so that if the answer is neither y or n the user must re-input their answer.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: (sigh)...spaces around `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove spaces on left side of equal sign to avoid declaring a variable with a space in its name. Add quotes to avoid problems with some characters (&<>|)

```
SET /p "answer=Hello user. Do you want to use this program? (y/n)"
```

The ignore case in the IF command does not include []. Also, add quotes to avoid problems with empty answers.

```
IF /i "%answer%"=="y" GOTO yes
```

Comment: thanks. Yes both stuff worked. By any chance is there a tool I can use to check my code for syntax errors in case a similar problem should arise?

Answer (score 1):

remove the space after `answer` :

```
SET /p answer= Hello user. Do you want to use this program? (y/n)
```

in your original code you are creating a variable named `%answer %` instead of `%answer%`

**EDIT** Remove also the rectangular brackets in `IF` conditions...

```
:ask
@echo off
SET /p answer= Hello user. Do you want to use this program? (y/n) 

IF /i "%answer%" == "y" GOTO :yes
IF /i "%answer%" == "n" (
 GOTO :no
) ELSE ( 
 ECHO Your input was not accepted. Please try again.
 GOTO :ask
)

:yes
rem

:no
rem
pause
```

Comment: thanks, but now it is saying [my input] was not expected at the time

This is shown after the first conditional statement

Comment: `IF [/i]` are you using these rectangular brackets in your code? Try to remove them and leave only `IF /I`

Comment: same thing happens :/